# Change English word in BibTeX-generated bibliography to Portuguese

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I'm using JabRef to do my thesis. For example, I have some references that are PhD or master thesis. So, they appear in English. But, I'm writing my thesis in Portuguese.

In the example below, I want to replace "PhD thesis" to "Tese de doutoramento". It is possible?

> de Moraes, S. V. M. (2008). Sntese e caracterizac~ao de hbridos a
>   base de slica contendo aminas alifaticas e aromaticas. PhD thesis,
>   Universidade Federal do Rio Grande do Sul, Brasil.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead, headheight=15.8pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\begin{document}

sfadsfsaçdjfsldjfsljdslk \citep{sol_gel}

\bibliography{Biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{my-apalike}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use `natbib`/`bibtex` or `biblatex`/`biber`?

Comment: I'm using natbib

Comment: As `babel` doesn't do anything you may need to modify the `.bst` file, or rather make a copy of it with a new name, and modify the copy. The `bst` file is the bibliographystyle, e.g. if you have `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, there is a file `plainnat.bst`. For more specific advice, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), to show how your document is set up.

Comment: Which bibliography style -- the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive --- do you use?

Comment: my .bst file is : my-apalike.bst

Comment: I had the same problem today and I solved it by using babelbib package (http://get-software.net/biblio/bibtex/contrib/babelbib/babelbib.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for updating your posting and indicating which bibliography style you employ. I trust that `my-apalike` is fairly similar to the "standard" `apalike` bibliography style.

You need to open the file `my-apalike.bst` in a text editor -- the program you use to edit your .tex files will do fine -- and look for certain hard-coded English-language terms and replace them with the corresponding Portuguese terms. Among these terms are

- `"Master's thesis"` (ca. line 668 in the unmodified version of the style file)
- `"PhD thesis"` (ca. line 698) -> `"Tese de doutoramento"`, right?
- `"others"` (224)
- `" and "` (225 and 891)
- `", editors "` and `", editor"` (257 and 258)
- `" of "` (line 321)
- `"number"` and `"Number"` (333 and 334)
- `" edition"` (twice, 352 & 353)
- `"In "` (433, 434)
- `"Technical Report"` (451)
- `"In"` (462)
- `"Volume"` (470)
- `" of "` (471)
- `"In"` (478)

After editing/updating `my-apalike.bst`, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the main .tex file to ensure that all changes are fullly propagated.

Answer (score 3):

Please check babelbib package documentation.

There one can read: "babelbib supports the BibTEX styles babplain,babplai3, babalpha, babunsrt, bababbrv, and bababbr3 that correspond to the standard bst files, but include international support as well as flexible typography".

Putting

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % for European Portuguese use portuguese
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{brazil}
```

in the preamble and using

```
\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}
```

works fine for me.

Please notice that, if you have references in any other language rather than Portuguese, these languages must be specified in the options of babel, and a language field must be added to each of these bibtex entries, otherwise we will get foreign language hyphenations wrong. Recall that the last language is the default language of your document. For example:

```
\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's not JabRef that will change anything, but the compiler. If you use `biblatex`and `babel`or `polyglossia`(the latter with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`) declaring portuguese at the main language, this will be automatic.

In addition, note that if you use `biber` to compile the bibliography, it can be saved in UTF8 format, letting you typeset directly accented letters.

Comment: yes, I use this commands in preambule: 
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

even so, it not works

Comment: Could we have a minimal (non)working example (it would be nice if you used use file contents for the bib entries).

Comment: Forgotten: what does the .bbl file say?

Comment: the file begins like this:\begin{thebibliography}{}

Answer (score 1):

As you did not provide a MWE I just assume, that you use `babel` and the following code should help as `babel` does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{moraes:2008,
    author = {de Moraes, S.V.M.},
    title = {The Portuguese  Title},
    school = {Universidade Federal do Rio Grande do Sul, Brasil},
    year = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  % literatur deutsch
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}        
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If you are not satisfied, you can use the following snippet.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{portuguese}{%      
  phdthesis ={Tese de doutoramento},
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't help the OP much, since he's not using `biblatex`, and `babel` didn't do anything. (See the comments to the question and the other answer.)

Comment: You're right. I posted this before he added some more information.